# Почему не запускается локальны сервер?

Tags: веб-программирование, openserver

Установил OpenServer, в настройках выбрал Mysql, запускаю сервер, а он выключается, если выберу "Не использовать" то сервер запускается. Как исправить?

Comment: есть логи, в которых пишется что не так

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему MySql уже установлен на локальной машине. Проверьте не занят ли у вас порт 3306 на локальном адресе. В командной строке введите команду:

```
C:\>netstat -ano
```

Если MySql уже стоит, нет смысла подключать модуль в OpenServer. Используйте ту базу, которая уже установлена.